# Find probabilty of having r matchsticks in one box when other is empty

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A mathematician carries a matchbox one each in both left and right pockets of his shirt. Initially,each matchbox contains $N$ matchsticks. Each time he wants a matchbox, he selects at random from the right or left pocket to get it.

Consider the moment when the mathematician discovers that a box is empty.

Find the probability that there are exactly $r$ matchsticks in one box when the other box is found empty.

**My Attempt**

When he finds that one box is empty and other contains $r$ matchsticks then he would have taken out a total of $2N-r$ matchsticks. But now how to get that $N$ matchsticks have come from one pocket.

Answer (score 4):

The number of routes starting at $(N,N)$ and ending at $(0,r)$ equals $\binom{2N-r}{N}$ and the same is true for the number of routes starting at $(N,N)$ and ending at $(r,0)$.

For each route the probability that this route will be taken equals $2^{r-2N}$.

That leads to probability $$\binom{2N-r}{N}2^{r-2N}\frac12+\binom{2N-r}{N}2^{r-2N}\frac12=\binom{2N-r}{N}2^{r-2N}$$that one of the routes $(N,N)\to(0,r)\to(-1,r)$  and $(N,N)\to(r,0)\to(r,-1)$ will be chosen.

Comment: For N=1, r=0, the probability is 1/2. Your expression gives 1/4.

Comment: Acutally, probability can't be larger than 1.

Comment: @SteveB My mistake was another. I just forgot to include the combination factor. Repaired now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only random variate in this problem is X, which indicates the box from which the mathematician picks each matchstick. Let be $K$, a new random variate that counts the number of picks from box A, ie the number of times X indicates "box A" in the experiment. Then $K$ has a binomial distribution (more about the binomial distribution [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)).

So we have by definition:

$P(K=k) =\binom nk p^n(1-p)^{n-k}$

with $n$ the total number of picks, $k$ the number of picks from box A, $p$ the probability of picking from box A.

Of course, the event "Box A is empty" (ie $K=N$) is equivalent to the event "$r$ matchsticks remain in box B" by definition, ie $P(r)=P(K=N)$.

Let's simplify $P(K=k)$ for $k=N$ and $p=1/2$:

$P(r)=P(K=N)=\binom nN \frac{1}{2^n}$

Substitute with $n=2N-r$ and we finally get:

$P(r)=\binom {2N-r}{N} \frac{1}{2^{2N-r}}$

Please tell me what you think.

Comment: I think you've left out a bit of reasoning, although your answer happens to be correct. What you have actually computed is the probability that after choosing 2N−r matches, the box in the left pocket, say, is empty, and the other has r matches. You need to multiply by the probability that he reaches for the empty box, that is $\frac12.$ Since the empty box is equally likely to be in the right pocket, you got the correct answer.

If you don't see my point, think about the solution if the mathematician reaches in his left pocket with probability .6 and his right pocket with probability .4.

Comment: I don't see your point indeed. The question is "what is the probability [...] when one box is empty". So why would we multiply by the probability of one box being empty? It's the starting point!

Comment: That's not what I said.

Comment: OK my bad. I use Binom to formulate an analytical relation between P and other parameters. Then I can forget probabilities and put the relation in a form that answers the question. If I get it well, you are questioning the step from probabilities to analyticaI formulation. This step is correct because the only (latent) random variate in the problem is X, which indicates the box from which the guy picks each matchstick. This is exactly the situation that the Binomial distribution describes, so I think that the reasoning is correct, no? Happy to discuss.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually correct answer of this question is in picture[image: i will explain how i came on this result in comment after some time]

Comment: You should add an explanation for this.

Comment: Now firstly i will explain combination term .Probability of choosing one matchstick from box 1 is 1/2 and same will be for box 2.Now we have to choose the box for getting matchstick 2N-r times .Now select N times from 2N -r times where we have to choose from box 1 and automatically we have to choose matchstics from box 2 in the left N-r trials .So these type of arrangements can be the given combination (2N-r)C(N)

Comment: @Sourabh Is that left side superscript on the C standard notation?

Comment: Now the second term . There is bit more logic behind it .As we know we have to get 2N-r matchstics so someome will think that the second tern should be (1/2)^2N-r but it not true .To know weather the box is empty or not We have to do one more trial and in that trial we have to choose the box 1 so that we came to know weather box is empty or not.Other wise we will choose box 2 and take matchstics from it and we will not able to know weather the other box is empty or not.

Comment: If I'm interpreting your notation correctly, if N=1 and r=0, the result is 1/4. I think it should be 1/2.

Comment: Here C represents combination in which we have to choose N terms out of 2N-r

Comment: So for N=1 and r=0, we get (2C1)*(1/2)^3 = 2*(1/8) = 1/4. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry your expression is wrong.  Consider N=2.  All possible cases are LL, LHL, LHH, HH, HLH, HLL. For r=2, HH and LL qualify.  Probability is 1/3.  Your expression doesn't give 1/3.

Comment: The answer is 1/4 and not 1/2 because to see the box is empty or not we have to select box one again in third trial and probability for it will become 1/4

Comment: First trial - a match is taken from a box. 2nd trial, 1/2 chance that the same box will be checked, so for r = 1, probability is 1/2. The chance that the bx with a match still in it is chosen is 1/2. 3rd trial, the chance that the selected box is empty is 1. 1/2 * 1 = 1/2 is the probability that r = 0.

Comment: Hey understand it. Now let us choose matchstick from first box first and then we choose from second box third time we will choose box 1 to get matchstick and we will see it is empty So probability became (1/2)×(1/2)×(1/2) now 2nd case we choose matchstich from second box first then we choose from first box and then we have to choose again from 1st box to see if it has any matchsticks left so in 2nd case probability again became 1/8 .So total probability is addition of the two cases and hence answer became 1/4

Comment: The two boxes are differntiable they are not like same coloured balls(☺️in probability

Comment: Do a sanity check on $N=1,r=1$ and $N=1,r=0$. Both probabilities should equalize $0.5$.

Comment: Can you explain  that how you to result that why for N=1 and r=1 probability is 1/2

Comment: In that case these are 2 possibilities. He chooses his right pocket twice or he chooses his left pocket twice. Both probabilities equal $0.25$ so addition gives $0.5$.

Comment: Please type your answers rather than posting an image.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: So now i got it in question it is not specified that which box is empty and which box have r matchstics left .So for every case the ans became twice of  the expression given by me