# Question on Banach matchbox problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I was looking through stackexchange for some answers regarding this problem and am curious on one answer in particular. I've posted it below. Here is the link: [Find probabilty of having r matchsticks in one box when other is empty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2935185/find-probabilty-of-having-r-matchsticks-in-one-box-when-other-is-empty/2935232#2935232)

***begin quote*** "

The number of routes starting at $(N,N)$ and ending at $(0,r)$ equals $\binom{2N-r}{N}$ and the same is true for the number of routes starting at $(N,N)$ and ending at $(r,0)$.

For each route the probability that this route will be taken equals $2^{r-2N}$.

That leads to probability $$\binom{2N-r}{N}2^{r-2N}\frac12+\binom{2N-r}{N}2^{r-2N}\frac12=\binom{2N-r}{N}2^{r-2N}$$ that one of the routes $(N,N)\to(0,r)\to(-1,r)$  and $(N,N)\to(r,0)\to(r,-1)$ will be chosen.

"

***end quote***

My question(s): **Question 1.)** Why would combinations be of use in this problem as wouldnt we consider the following distinct events:

(1) pick match #1A from box A, match #1B from box B , then match #2A
vs

(2) pick match #1B from box B, then #1A from box A, then #2A from box A.

where I've numbered the elements of box A and B 1 through $N$ in each box.

**Question 2.)** Why are there $\binom{2N-r}{N}$ ways to be left with $r$ matches in a single box? It seems like you choose $N$ then you will not take away enough matches to be left with only $r$ total and $2N - r - N = 1N - r \neq r$ .

Thanks for the help!

Comment: One thing I can never understand about probability puzzles like this is roughly 'how do you know that you have a probability space?' People say like oh the probability that this path is selected is $x$, but I always think: How do you know that your probabilities sum to 1. They must 'have to' for some reason but I've never seen it articulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1.  We don't care which matches have been pulled out, or in what order; only how many have been pulled out of each box.  You can describe the situation as a sequence of $R$'s and $L$'s, meaning rights and lefts, so it just like heads and tails in tossing a coin.

Question 2.  If he exhausts the matches in the left pocket say, and has $r$ matches left in the right pocket, then he has used $2N-r$ matches in all, and drawn $N$ of them from the left pocket.  So this is the same as asking how many sequences of $N$ $R$'s and $N-r$ $L$'s are there?

$${(2N-r)!\over N!(N-r)!}={2N-r\choose N}$$